# Angular js create listeners and send mail by condition

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs

I am sending data from the server to the client with the socket. I show the objects I have sent with ng-repeat in the table. When I click with ng-click, I can see the selected index. there is no problem. but my objects are constantly being updated.

What I want is that after clicking on the line in the table, I will write the necessary conditions in the form for the selected index. Example: I want you to send mail when the data in the object is 3 and I am 5. In other words, after creating the condition, you will be a listener and send an e-mail when the condition is met.I hope I could tell what I wanted

Controller.js :

```
app.controller('dashController', ['$scope',($scope) =>{
   const socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3000');

 socket.on('ozkaynak',(data)=>{
            $scope.equity =data.equity;
            $scope.$apply(); 
            //console.log($scope.equity);
     }) 
   })
        $scope.selectedRow = null
        $scope.getData = function(index){
        $scope.selectedRow = index;
      }
```

Part of pug.file:

```
    #oTab.card-body
                    .table-responsive
                      table.table.table-stripped.table-hover(cellspacing='0')
                        thead.thead.bg-primary.text-white
                          tr
                            th.th-sm Musteri No
                            th.th-sm Ozkaynak
                        tbody
                          tr(ng-repeat="e in equity track by $index" ng-click="getData($index)" ng-class="{selected:$index ==selectedRow}")
                            td {{e.mNo}}
                            td {{e.ozkynk}}
#alarm.card
                  form.text-center.border-light.p-5(action='#!')
                    i.fas.fa-bell
                    p.h4.mb-2 Alarm
                    // Subject
                    .form-check.form-check-inline
                      input#inlineRadio1.form-check-input(type='radio', name='inlineRadioOptions', value='option1')
                      label.form-check-label(for='inlineRadio1')
                        h6 Sms
                    .form-check.form-check-inline
                      input#inlineRadio2.form-check-input(type='radio', name='inlineRadioOptions', value='option2')
                      label.form-check-label(for='inlineRadio2')
                        h6 E-Mail
                    select.mdb-select.h6.mb-3
                      option(value='', disabled='') Choose option
                      option(value='1', selected='') Level1
                      option(value='2') Level2
                      option(value='3') Feature request
                      option(value='4') Feature request
                    select.mdb-select.h6.mb-3
                      option(value='', disabled='') Choose option
                      option(value='1', selected='') EmailorNumber
                      option(value='2') Level2
                      option(value='3') Feature request
                      option(value='4') Feature request
                    // Message
                    .form-group
                      textarea#exampleFormControlTextarea2.form-control.rounded-0(rows='3', placeholder='Message')
                    // Send button
                    button.btn.btn-info.btn-block(type='submit') Alarm
```